# Why doesn't this image move when the key is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

***Python*** and ***Tkinter*** nebwie. I tried making an image in tkinter and have it move using the arrows. The image shows just it should, but when I try to move it using the arrows, it doesn't work at all. Any idea why? I use ***python 2.7.18*** and I'm on the latest version of ***Ubuntu***

```
from Tkinter import *


############
#things

w = 500
h = 500

width=w
height=h


#############

######################################################################
#window

window = Tk()
window.title("Moving image")
canvas = Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas.pack()
my_image = PhotoImage(file="/home/user/Documents/ddd.png")
canvas.create_image(260, 125, anchor = NW, image=my_image)

#######################################################################

################################
#var

def up(event):
  x = 0
  y = -10
  canvas.move(my_image, x, y)

def down(event):
  x = 0
  y = 10
  canvas.move(my_image, x, y)

def left(event):
   x = -10
   y = 0
   canvas.move(my_image, x, y)

def right(event):
  x = 10
  y = 0
  canvas.move(my_image, x, y)



###############################

###############################
#binds
window.bind("<Up>", up)
window.bind("<Down>", down)
window.bind("<Left>", left)
window.bind("<Right>", right)

window.mainloop()

##############################
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to move the wrong object. Use the object, which is returned by `canvas.create_image`:

```
image_id = canvas.create_image(260, 125, anchor = NW, image=my_image)

...

canvas.move(image_id, x, y)
```

Alternatively, you can attach a tag to the image:

```
canvas.create_image(260, 125, anchor=NW, image=my_image, tag="move")

...

canvas.move("move", x, y)
```

This will move all objects, which have this specific tag attached.

Comment: Do you think instead of storing in variable, making a 
tag makes it any better? Like `canvas.create_image(...tag='img_id')` and `canvas.move('image_id', x, y)`